# computed column base on ranked position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a new column(computed) to assign points based on the positions in the positions column as in this image

[image: image with computed rank column]

I have tried this query below but my quest was not successful: I seek your assistance please help

**query in sql server**

[image: sqlquery I tried in sql server]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots as code.  Code is text, if it is an image we cannot run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do rank using `apply` like that.  You'll always get "1".  Use a subquery:

```
select . . .
from (select ae.*, rank() over (order by averagemark desc) as position
      from agriculturalentries
     ) cross join
     (values (case when rank >= 13 then 150 - rank * 10 end) ) as v(pointsearned);
```

I find the arithmetic easier to type than your `case`, but you can use the more verbose form.

You might ask why `rank()` always returns "1" in your query.  That is because `apply` only considers one row at a time (as written).  The rank over that row is necessarily "1".

Comment: @Dean . . . Not to be rude, and as the OP you can accept any answer you like, but I'm curious why you accepted an equivalent answer posted half an hour after this one?  In particular, this one explains why your version doesn't work in addition to answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
With AllMarks AS 
(SELECT
CompetitorID,
ApiEntryId,
AverageMark,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AverageMark)AS RankPosition

-- Add other columns
FROM ApicultureEntries
)
SELECT
a.*,(CASE WHEN  a.RankPosition < 14 THEN 150 - RankPosition * 10 ELSE NULL  END) AS PositionEarned
FROM AllMarks AS a
```